# Pinterest Integration Using functions.php

Tags: functions, content, code, html

I use a theme to build an portfolio.

I´d like to add an pinterest "pin-it button" into the fuctions.php:
Facebook, Google+ an Twitter were done, just the pinterest won´t work.

Can´t found the the wrong code.
This ist my code:

```
function share_this($content){
if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
$content .= '<div class="share-this">' .  
      /* Facebook */
      '<div class="facebook-like-button">' . 
            '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='. urlencode( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . 
            '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=200&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"' . 
            'scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>' .
      '</div>' . 

     /* Pinterest */
    '<div class="pinterest-it-button">' 
             '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php echo get_thumbnail(); ?>
             '&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>'.
    '</div>' . 

     /* Googgle+ */
    '<div class="plusone"><g:plusone size="medium" href="'.get_permalink().'"></g:plusone></div>' .
     /* Twitter */
    '<div><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a></div>' .

'</div>';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, english isn´t my first language. This code is from functions.php, without using an plugin. I think it´s a problem of the differnt quotes ' "

Comment: @ogni No offense. By `plugins <=> function(s)`, I meant to say that a plugin basically constitutes one or more functions. So, you should NOT really worry about using plugins. What you should worry about is, finding a well coded and well maintained plugin. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several errors in your code. The biggest was that the function didn't even have a closing bracket, but we can probably assume that was just not copied into your post, otherwise nothing would have been working for you.

This is a filter on the content right?

It looks like you want to append these shares after your post content.
If that's the case than you would need this line as well:

```
add_filter('the_content','share_this');
```

Other than that, you were trying to close php tags and open them in your statement where you are appending string data to the `$content` variable.  You were also trying to echo data and used functions to echo instead of return (for example `the_title` echos instead of `get_the_title` which returns the value).

Instead of one big string appended to your content, I cleaned things up using an array-building method, but multiple `$shares .=` would have worked too.

This should work although I have not tested it.

```
<?php
function share_this($content) {
    if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
        global $post;

        $link = esc_attr(get_permalink($post->ID));
        $title = esc_attr(get_the_title($post->ID));

        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post-ID);
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id);
        $thumb = $image_url[0];

        $shares = array();
        $shares[] = '<div class="share-this">';

        /* Facebook */
        $shares[] = '<div class="facebook-like-button"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='.$link.'&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=200&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>';

        /* Pinterest */
        $shares[] = '<div class="pinterest-it-button"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$link.'&amp;media='.$thumb.'description='.$title.' class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script></div>';

        /* Googgle+ */
        $shares[] = '<div class="plusone"><g:plusone size="medium" href="'.$link.'"></g:plusone></div>';

        /* Twitter */
        $shares[] = '<div><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a></div>';

        $shares[] = '</div>';

        return $content . implode("\n", $shares);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 : Kudos for the creativity and text interpretation! Much better than repairing a not working and incomplete code: very nice sample of clean, simple and hooked Answer :)

Comment: @ogni : the *Way of the Stack* is : *instead* of saying "thanks", *press* the up-vote button :))

Answer (score 2):

You are building the URL Wrong since first it needs to be urlencoded and 2nd what is `get_thumbnail()` does it print the full img tag? and 3rd you are echoing it out.

anyway try this

```
/* Pinterest */
$baseurl = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?';
$url = 'url='.urlencode(get_permalink());
$mediaUrl = '&media='.urlencode(wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id()));
$description = '&description='.urlencode(get_the_title());
$fullURL = $baseurl.$url.$mediaUrl.$description;
$content .= '<div class="pinterest-it-button">
<a href="'.$fullURL.'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
</div>';
```

Comment: @Thanks Bainternet:  `'<a href="'.$fullURL.'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>`  'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /functions.php on line 265'

Comment: @Bainternet - you used `the_title()` inside the `$description` variable.

Comment: @EvanMattson nice catch, as for ogni there is no syntax error with the above code, create a pastebin of your functions.php file and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simple php syntax. You can't use opening and closing php braces `<?php` and `?>` within variable assignment and separate strings and variables must be concatenated by a dot `.`

Follow the G+ and Facebook buttons as examples. I also assume you want to `return` your results?